# Lista de acrônimos no latex

Tags: lista, latex

Boa tarde! Estou com um problema na lista de acrônimos no meu ficheiro latex.
Os acrônimos aparecem sinalizados no texto de forma correta mas a lista dos acrônimos simplesmente não aparece.
No meu ficheiro dissertation.sty tenho o seguinte código:
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\renewcommand*{\glstextformat}{\textbf}

e no ficheiro dissertation.tex tenho logo no início da página:
\makeglossaries

e no sítio onde eu quero que apareça a lista tenho:
% Acronyms
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,nonumberlist, title={Acronyms}]

% Glossary
\printglossary[title={Glossary}, nonumberlist]

Tenho uma colega que também tem os mesmos comandos com os ficheiros super idênticos, no dela aparece a lista direitinha e no meu não. Agradeço muito se alguém conseguir ajudar. Obrigada!